# Google Php Api : How to set Google_client object in unambigous way

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I have an mobile app that process the login and services authentication of an google account and the response datas are these : access_token,id_token,refresh_token and serverauthcode. and it passes these datas to a web server.

How to use these datas to directly set them to Google_Client object without  having an redirection url and services authentication since the job has been done on the mobile app. Thank you!

```
 These are my code:

function accessService(){
  $client_obj = $this->googleAccessToken();
  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client_obj);
  $calendarId = 'primary';
            $optParams = array(
              'maxResults' => 10,
              'orderBy' => 'startTime',
              'singleEvents' => TRUE,
              'timeMin' => date('c'),
            );
  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
  print_r($results);

  //Im getting Error here in this part 
  // Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  //"error": "unauthorized_client",
  //"error_description": "Unauthorized"}
 }

function googleAccessToken(){
    $idtoken = 'id_token_from_app';
    $refreshtoken = 'refresh_token_from_app';
    $access_token = 'access_token_from_app';

      $credentials=array('id_token'=>$idtoken,'refresh_token'=>$refreshtoken,'access_token'=>$access_token);

$client = new Google_client();
$client->setApplicationName('CalendarApp');
$client->setAuthConfig('path_to_my_client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessToken(json_encode($credentials));

return $client;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? your question is too broad.

Comment: Hi @DaniloKobold just edited my question and put my codes. thank you!